# What is the difference of dig results between domain and www.domain

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

I found a domain name which gives different results for following dig commands. Lets assume the domain name is domain.com.

Commands:

```
dig domain.com
dig www.domain.com
```

Is anyone know what are the reasons for getting different results for this queries?

Comment: Of course you get different results. Those are two different domain names.

Comment: More Specifically two different FQDNs....

Comment: Very nice question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're two different queries, why should they give the same results?

Comment: My apologies if it is a silly question. I'm new to this DNS stuff. I can understand that we can host DNS domain.com, but I believe that we cannot host another DNS like www.domain.com. Is that right or wrong? I have only seen www.domain.com things as aliases in web servers which pointing by domain.com dns record.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. They're two different names, as different as `co.uk` and `guardian.co.uk`. The DNS system doesn't care about conventions about how the `com` TLD or `www` host name is used.

Answer (score 1):

One is a domain and the other is a subdomain. The fact thet they very often do have the same address doesn't mean they have to.